# Does the singularity travel along the time axis?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, coordinate-systems, event-horizon

Let's assume that all matter travels along `t` axis roughly at the speed of light, in the direction of worldline for rest mass.

Let's also assume that there is a singularity (or other sufficiently compact object) formed by collapse of neutron star of sufficient mass. It has an event horizon around it.

Should we assume that this singularity also travels along the same `t` axis that the matter around singularity experiences? Wikipedia, for example, has contradictory images to illustrate that.

On the first sight, we assume that the event horizon that we observe still has a singularity inside it *now*, i.e. on the same place on *t* as other matter around the event horizon. This is supported by image when all world lines are bent but never going backwards on *t*:
[image: Event horizon]

On the second sight, all the world lines inside this event horizon (from our point of view) now point towards the singularity, and no longer point at `t`. They're at least orthogonal to `t`. This is suggested by the possibility of [closed timelike curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve)

It's easy to imagine that a singularity is a "bubble" of spacetime floating along the rest of the matter towards `t` just like an air bubble in a liquid would, even if there's no movement of air inside the bubble. But you may also imagine that a singularity is a fixed point of spacetime and it protrudes a long sausage-like bubble of event horizon in the direction of `t` axis, as seen in 4 dimension spacetime.

I would also like to see some math that would prove or deny either view or any third one, if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question, but I don't like using the diagram there for black hole spacetimes, when considering inside the horizon (The Schwarzschild coordinates are for the external region only). It seems better to work on a conformal diagram in [Kruskal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates), where it's obvious the singularity is in the future of all forward light cones within the horizon. Then the singularity at $r=0$ represents a point in the future.
If this hasn't answered any of the questions, would you be able to clarify?

Comment: The singularity doesn't evolve in time: it's precisely defined to be a point where geodesics cannot be extended, hence it's fixed in time. Any trajectories (timelike or null) inside the event horizon necessarily eventually hits the singularity at $r=0$ where it then ends. I'm not sure if this links with either of the views you put forward?

Comment: @Eletie If it does not evolve in time, how does it coincide with the rest of universe which move forward on `t`? Can we say that this singularity exists in the future of the space outside of its event horizon? If it does not, then why event horizon does not disappear? Can you go back on `t` axis inside singularity while coming closer to the singularity? Or you're just moving forward on `t` but slower?

Comment: You need to be precise with what we're talking about here. For a Schwarzschild black hole in the Kruskal–Szekeres diagram (previous link), this is the spacetime for the 'whole universe' in a sense. It includes everything: the spacelike and timelike and null infinities. The black holes (which isn't formed from collapse) is past and future eternal (ignoring quantum effects and evaporation). Region I contains our universe from t = -∞ to t =+∞. Inside the horizon, t and r coords swap characters (r is now timelike and t is spatial). The singularity is at the constant time r=0.

Comment: @Eletie You're talking from "within" the event horizon. I'm taking from "outside" the event horizon. If we see an event horizon *now*, does it mean that the singularity also exists *now* (current timeframe)? If so, the singularity itself should be moving along our own world line. Won't it? Why would singularity move along `t` if it's spatial? Why would we observe it if it doesn't?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about 'observing' - we can't observe a singularity or anything within the horizon. This is all very clear in the Kruskal diagram. It explicitly shows worldlines with constant radius $r > r_{s}$ evolving forward in time, with the horizon at $r=r_s$. The black hole is eternal in the future.

Comment: the concept of 'now' at different spacetime locations doesn't even make sense in GR: you can pick whatever time slices you want. But regardless, for any 'now' you choose, for any observer in the universe, the (eternal Schwarzschild) black hole exists and its singularity is at $r=0$. For a collapsing star you can ask how long it takes for the singularity to form, but that's a different question entirely.

Comment: We can't observe the singularity but we can observe the event horizon since we are attracted towards it. You are saying that for any observer in the universe, the black hole exists and its singularity is at (r = 0, t = tcur) where tcur is local time just outside the event horizon (I imagine that time is meaningless on the event horizon and may be infinitely dilated in the epsilon area, but it's defined just outside that area). So for the external observer, event horizon is basically a worldsheet and (imaginary) singularity a worldline for practical purposes. That would be #1 in my question.

Comment: "observe the event horizon since we are attracted towards it", " time is meaningless on the event horizon and may be infinitely dilated in the epsilon area", " event horizon is basically a worldsheet and (imaginary) singularity a worldline".
Too many of these statements seem incorrect or misunderstood, so I can't answer your questions (and this comment thread is getting too long). The spacetime geometry cannot be described how you want to describe it, (constant time slices outside and within the horizon). I'd advice picking up a good textbook on GR that covers black hole spacetimes.

Comment: I'm afraid that "these statements seem incorrect or misunderstood" because we don't seem to use math and instead try to hand wave our way through this. Even if I would pick a textbook on GR it's doubtful that it would answer my specific question, and when it does I can't validate whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: I can attempt to write out the math, if you tell me what level you're familiar with?

Comment: Let's try the one on which it may be represented without loss of understanding.

Comment: There is no loss of understanding in making the change to Kruskal coordinates and finding the conformal diagram. This is the best way to see the global spacetime properties. You can't expect me to derive everything about black holes with no starting point. Are you considering Schwarzschild black holes, or black holes formed from gravitational collapse? If you want to see that mathematics, you need to have studied GR and spherically symmetric spacetimes specifically as a prerequisite. Do you know what geodesic completeness is and how to define a singularity (whether it's timelike or spacelike)?

Comment: If you provide some mathematics yourself, of where you're at and what you're struggling to understand, or can make the concepts more clear, I can help, but currently there's nothing for me to work with. It seems you're fundamentally misunderstanding the spacetime structure of the universe. In conformal diagrams we're showing the *whole* structure, for all time. We don't think of a black hole as a region of space 'evolving through time'. Look at the conformal diagrams [here](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/physics/coursewikis/GGR/book/ggr/penrose) which also includes dynamical collapse.

Comment: @safesphere Since we're on physics and not on math stackexchange I expect the answer to apply to astrophysical black holes. I assume that Kerr and Schwarzschild singularities may both be used to talk about black holes, each taking away a subset of detail which are not relevant to a given scenario. We can also assume that "mass inside an event horizon" is identical to "singularity" for practical purposes, but I'm not sure if there's modelling of real stellar space holes' contents.

Comment: There is no such thing as a singularity. There is only a theory that can't deal with microstates of matter and radiation at very high density.

Comment: Is there such thing as Event Horizon then @FlatterMann? If there is, does it travel along the time axis of the enclosing flat-ish space?

Comment: No, there is no such THING as an event horizon, either. Event horizons are a mathematical prediction of the theory. The time axis travel thing is, for all I can tell, YouTube physics. I wouldn't take that very seriously, either. There is a lot of that kind of entertaining stuff out there that just ain't so.

Comment: What's that thing at the center of out galaxy then @FlatterMann

Comment: "That thing" is a lot of matter in a very small volume of space. Nobody knows what that much matter in a very small volume of space actually does. That's for future physicists to find out.

Comment: I don't see how having a lot of matter in a very small volume of space will not be indistinguishable from an event horizon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can't observe the singularity but we can observe the event horizon since we are attracted towards it.

This comment reflects a Newtonian approach and neglects GR where the interpretation is that the collapsed mass causes spacetime curvature (and a "fall" towards the event horizon). Similarly:

> event horizons do move, for example, a black hole may be ejected from a galaxy or two event horizons may merge. This means we can't escape discussing the movement of singularities in 4 dimensions space even if we wanted.

This comment seems one-sided. We can observe a black hole being ejected from a galaxy by considerable forces and follow its path along a spacetime metric, but that black hole is shaping the spacetime it moves through and from the perspective we cannot observe but rely on GR to assume, anything the black hole comes in direct contact with (and time itself in the predicted interior) is moving towards the singularity.

At the risk of seeming facetious, one might well ask: Does time travel along the singularity axis?

Also: It might be worth reconsidering the original question where the singularity is replaced by a hypothetical connective wormhole.

Please see this article: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/acba86

The empirical evidence points to a supermassive black hole ejected from a galaxy along with a volume of gas. In the black hole's wake, the gas has been compressed into stars, the trail being some 200,000 light years in length. The black hole is not moving particularly quickly (at only 0.15% of *c*) but it is moving and we could estimate where a new observation of it will occur at a given point in our future.

From the evidence available, it appears that while material encountering an event horizon irrevocably becomes part of the black hole's local universe, that material and the black hole in its entirety (singularity included) is not "immune" to gravitational interactions with other bodies that occur in observable time intervals.

We can't assume that material outside the boundary of the observable universe is unable to affect the observable universe (and vice versa) so it's still a plausible part of our spacetime.

Comment: I would prefer a snap of an answer than a barrel of more questions. I understand most of your questions but do not know answers.

Comment: @alamar It's not a collapsed neutron star but a much smaller black hole, the size of a pea. It's on a path towards you but Physics Stack Exchange sends you advance notification; you see it coming and run for your life. For a short period of time the tiny beast is travelling along with you, somewhere behind your skull. Fortunately your belt snaps, your pants fall down and trip you up. The black hole whizzes past; you are saved. In that case, I think we'd all be forgiven for assuming that the singular thing was travelling along your time axis. Then the hammock snaps; it was all just a dream.

Comment: But the question "why" remains.

Comment: @alamar There is a link added to the answer above (recent observations) that you might be interested in.

Comment: I've accepted the answer but the question about physical explanation of gravity interaction between singularity and outside matter still stands.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to talk about black hole singularities at a level beyond a pop-sci documentary, then some fundamentals of GR need to be firmly established ahead of time.

---

> Let's assume that all matter travels along $t$ axis roughly at the speed of light, in the direction of worldline for rest mass.

There is no $t$ axis. All massive particles travel along their worldlines, which are determined by the spacetime geometry and any forces which they might be subjected to. If you focus on a given massive particle, then you can construct a coordinate system $x$ (perhaps only in a small neighborhood of its worldline) such that its trajectory is $x(\tau) = (c\tau,0,0,0)$ - which you could loosely describe as the particle traveling along the $x^0 \equiv ct$ axis. However, there is no unique way (and in general, no way *at all*) to extend this coordinate system to cover the entire spacetime.

In the cartoon below, I've drawn three worldlines (black, red, and blue), and defined a coordinate chart $x$ in a neighborhood of the blue worldline. The grid on the right represents the coordinate chart, in which the blue worldline is simply a straight vertical line along the $x^0\equiv ct$ axis.

[image]

---

> Let's also assume that there is a singularity (or other sufficiently compact object) formed by collapse of neutron star of sufficient mass. It has an event horizon around it.

The local spacetime geometry can be diagrammed by attaching the light cone to each spacetime point. In such a diagram, an event horizon is characterized by all of the forward light cones along the horizon pointing inward. In the cartoon below, the forward light cones are specified by the arrows, and the horizon is denoted by the squiggly purple line.

[image]

In particular, a spacetime with a black hole might look like this, with the singularity denoted by the red double squiggle:

[image]

Note that unlike the event horizon, the singularity is **not** a point (or set of points) in the spacetime. It is not a part of the spacetime at all, in much the same way as the hole in a punctured sheet of paper is not part of the paper.

Here's another cartoon - this time of a black hole which forms due to gravitational collapse, and a few worldlines of in-falling matter (note: not necessarily in free-fall) shown in blue.

[image]

---

Having dazzled you with spacetime diagrams, we can now address your main question.

> Should we assume that this singularity also travels along the same t axis that the matter around singularity experiences?

As may be clear from the diagrams, this question doesn't really make sense. There is no unique $t$-axis, and the singularity is not even a part of spacetime. Furthermore, once you get inside the horizon, every timelike curve terminates at the singularity and so to the extent the singularity is anything, it is more akin to a moment in the future than it is to a point in space - loosely, the singularity does not consist of a worldline along some $t$-axis, but rather the place where every possible $t$-axis (inside the horizon) *ends*.

To make that point more clear, we can decompose the spacetime into spacelike surfaces of simultaneity, which I'll denote in my next cartoon with ticked green lines. Whenever you assign a spatial position to a point in spacetime, what you're (perhaps implicitly) doing is decomposing the spacetime into such a family of surfaces. Each surface is to be understood as a representation of **space** (not space**time**) at a given instant; the fact that the set of such surfaces is highly non-unique is what we mean when we say that there is no universal sense of simultaneity (or "now") in GR.

[image]

---

> Okay - but then, how would the star-forming black home moving at 0.15 c would look like on such chart? The one mentioned in the article linked by another answer.

Let me try to provide some clearer interpretation for the cartoons. The diagrams which I've drawn up to this point (with the exception of the first one) make no reference whatsoever to any coordinate systems, or to the observations of any hypothetical observers. The naïve, 2D geometry of the various features I depicted - e.g. the fact that the singularity is a vertical line - is an artifact of how I drew the cartoon, and does not have a physical interpretation. You could imagine drawing my cartoons on an elastic sheet, and cutting the singularity away with a pair of scissors. You may squash or twist the remaining sheet however you'd like - the physical spacetime being depicted remains unchanged. The fact that the singularity is not actually a *part* of the spacetime means that it doesn't have a particular shape, size, or position.

If we assign coordinates to the spacetime, then we can get a better sense of what an observer might actually see or experience by interpreting those coordinates physically. This is perhaps the trickiest part of GR, at least for beginners.

In the following picture, I have diagrammed the formation of a black hole by in-falling matter, which I depict by a gray region. Below the spacetime diagram, I show a spacelike slice (green) which is to be interpreted as a snapshot of the spacetime at $t=0$, long before the formation of the black hole.

[image]

We may assign coordinates to our spacetime in the following way. First, we populate our $t=0$ slice with (massless) graduate students whose velocity along the slice is zero; their worldlines are depicted in blue. Observe that the of the (gray) in-falling matter is initially at rest with respect to our students. The green slice is the set of events where all of their wristwatches read $t=0$.

We then allow the system to evolve. The next slice will be the set of events where all of the wristwatches read $t=1$, then $t=2$, and so on. By doing this, we decompose our spacetime into slices (along which all of the graduate students' watches are synchronized).

Every event in the spacetime lies on one of the graduate students' worldlines. The time coordinate for that event will be the time on the corresponding graduate student's wristwatch, and the spatial coordinates for that event will be the graduate student's initial position on the $t=0$ slice.

As the black hole forms, our slices become "deformed" due to kinematic and gravitational time dilation. The evolution of the spacetime is shown on the left side of the following figure, and the corresponding coordinate chart is shown on the right.

[image]

The region in red is not part of the coordinate chart (or indeed, part of the spacetime itself). We see that the singularity is the place where the worldlines of our unfortunate graduate students end. It is **not** a point in space; rather, for a given graduate student, the singularity is to be understood as a *moment in time*. For those graduate students who enter the event horizon, avoiding the singularity is like us avoiding next Wednesday.

Because the red double squiggle is not even a part of the spacetime, we cannot meaningfully assign it coordinates. We can, however, discuss the coordinates of the event horizon (shown in purple). At any given time (i.e. along any green slice), we observe that the event horizon constitutes the surface of a sphere, which is centered at a point which does not move as time goes on. In that precise sense we can say that in these coordinates, the black hole is at rest.

If we want to see what a moving black hole looks like, we can repeat the above procedure with a different initial slice. This time, we will choose a slice and a cohort of graduate students in such a way that the initial distribution of in-falling matter is **not** at rest, but rather moving to the left:

[image]

Decomposing our spacetime into slices and assigning coordinates like before, we obtain the following result:

[image]

This is what a moving black hole looks like. We see that the "central point" of the event horizon is moving to the left with the same speed as the initial distribution of in-falling matter.

Comment: In all the charts singularity looks like a line or ray drawn along the axis τ, it seems that the implied answer is "yes". After all, it is not a red dot or a red line going sideways left or right.

Comment: Another interesting takeaway from your drawings is that singularity is formed later (further away on τ) than the formation of event horizon. Perhaps that may prevent singularities from forming at all, but that is another question.

Comment: @alamar The explicit, repeated answer is **no**. There is no $\tau$ axis, nor does such a thing even make sense, as $\tau$ is the proper time along a worldline, not a spacetime coordinate. You cannot simply look at one of those cartoons and say "ah, the red line is vertical, therefore it is along the $t$-axis."

Comment: @alamar Coordinate systems in GR are subtle, and when you start talking about black holes and singularities then the subtleties grow even more. My attempt was to provide a visual picture of why the singularity of a black hole cannot be understood as a point in space, so talking about it "traveling" is nonsensical; admittedly though, this requires quite a lot of advanced study. If you do not feel prepared for a proper mathematical treatment, then that's fine - but the take-away from my answer should be that the answer to your question is *no*.

Comment: Okay - but then, how would the star-forming black home moving at 0.15 c would look like on such chart? The one mentioned in the article linked by another answer.

Comment: @alamar I've added a substantial section to my answer to provide some more intuition for what the cartoons actually mean, and to define two coordinate systems in which the black hole is respectively at rest and moving. Note in particular how the singularity is *not* a position in space. When we talk about the velocity of a black hole, we are talking about the motion of the "center" of the event horizon, which (contrary to what you might expect) is not the same thing as the singularity.

Comment: I understand how singularity is not a position in space, but it may still be a position in *spacetime*. The whole though experiment is devised to understand why we still observe the black hole's gravity throughout the spacetime even as its contents are no longer available for observation.

Comment: @alamar The singularity is **not** a part of spacetime - that's what being a singularity *means*. A point in spacetime is an *event*, and the singularity isn't an event either. 

As to your other question, you experience gravity because spacetime is curved. Before a black hole is formed, that curvature is due to the presence of matter (the gray region in my cartoon). As that matter collapses to a progressively smaller region, the increase in curvature causes a horizon to develop, which serves as a point of no return for matter.

Comment: Soon afterward, a singularity develops behind the horizon, which can be loosely understood as the moment in time where an in-falling worldline will end. At all points in this process, the spacetime is curved - even far away from the initial distribution of collapsing matter. Nearby, the details of that curvature change as the matter collapses - the curvature at the center of the collapsing cloud increases without bound until a singularity is formed. Far away, however, the curvature doesn't change much (if at all).

Comment: The existence of this curvature is not predicated on the existence of matter which you can freely interact with, so I'm ultimately not sure how to answer your question. The fact that matter has fallen behind a horizon doesn't mean that the curvature of the surrounding spacetime should magically disappear.

Comment: This is not obvious. For example, if you deform a bubble's membrane, it is often possible to pop off a secondary bubble which will no longer interact with parent membrane.

Comment: @alamar Well, spacetime isn't a bubble. To be clear, I'm not saying that it should be *obvious* that the gravitational influence of matter should persist after it falls behind the horizon, only that it is *true*. On the other hand, your question is predicated on the intuitive assumption that it should *disappear*, which is not the case. Letting go of that assumption goes a long way toward answering your question.

Comment: From a mathematical standpoint, if you restrict your attention to the vacuum region outside of a spherically-symmetric distribution of matter undergoing gravitational collapse, then the spacetime in that region is stationary and so the metric components (and therefore the components of the curvature tensor) can be taken to be time-independent. Whether that is obvious or not depends on your experience with differential equations and differential geometry.

Answer (score 1):

In a curved spacetime there is no unique coordinate chart that covers all of spacetime, so the whole notion of "the time axis" is ill-defined. Moreover, the singularity itself is not part of spacetime, and so cannot be said to "move" through spacetime; it does not have a world line. You could try to construct some kind of world tube that encloses the singularity, and seperates it from the rest of spacetime; the event horizon consititutes something like that. And you could then pretend that the singularity "follows" a path through spacetime that is inside that world tube, and for the purposes of someone sufficiently far away that would work. But it would be unwise to extrapolate that too far. In particular it would not well describe the spacetime inside the event horizon. Remember that *any* system of coordinates you construct will break down at the singularity -- that's what being a singularity means.

Comment: I am trying to understand why we keep observing an event horizon instead of it vanishing along with its gravity, possible by continuing its existence on unconnected coordinate chart. Unfortunately your answer does not help much.

Comment: If you really want to understand this it's probably best to dig into the details of relativity. In particular, remember that there's no universal choice of time coordinate (no "now" that all observers can agree on). Even if you take one observer and arbitrarily use their choice of "now", that doesn't extend throughout spacetime in a consistent way, any more than one observer's choice of "up" can be usefully extended over the whole surface of the Earth.

Comment: A number of comments removed. Friendly reminder that answering questions here is a volunteer activity; our community is not a consulting service.

Answer (score 0):

@Eletie I think Alamar's question, with the expectation that the black hole evolves with time, is based more on concepts, such as: if the singularity does not evolve with time, then how can we say that a massive object has collapsed to form a singularity - a time-independent singularity would either exist in that position (according to some "local observer") for all time or would appear then vanish; or that if the black hole was truly time independent it would not be able to evolve and emit Hawking radiation! My expectation is that, because Hawking radiation (not to mention singularities in general) necessitate knowledge of quantum gravity in some sense, one cannot provide a good answer to this question at this time.
@Alamar In order to avoid contradictions, one must conclude that the black hole is locally time dependent in the sense that an external observer would be able to determine that a massive object which was present has collapsed to form a black hole (e.g., it is implicitly assumed that the singularity will not replace the massive object that collapsed to form it for all time and that the singularity will exist at least until it evaporates). However, this does not mean that the singularity can be placed in the same coordinate chart as that used by the external observer.
Basically, the answer to your question might be too complicated to be answered here or at present.

Comment: I don't think it's unanswerable in a sense like questions "does God exist" or "how universe came to be". I think there should be a runnable mathematical model which simulates spacetime with black hole in it and gives an implicit answer.

Comment: I mean that it may be not be answerable without knowledge of quantum gravity. As no full theory of quantum gravity has been accepted as of yet, it may not be a question that may be answered at present without making several potentially incorrect assumptions. That is not to say that it can never be answered, just that it may not be able to be answered currently.

Comment: @PrawwarP sorry but I disagree. The question is about classical GR, where we have a very good understanding of the large scale structure of spacetime. Ok, singularities themselves necessarily will end up being tangled up with quantum physics, but the question isn't about quantum gravity. Similarlyy, ignoring the semi-classical calculations, hawking radiation isn't a factor. This is why I was particular when talking about past eternal Schwarzschild black holes (which of course aren't physical, but it's in the figure in the question).

Comment: It's a fact that classical black holes, once formed, their horizon (and everything within) exists at all future times with respect to the external universe. Once purtubations have settled within finite time (there's theorems that make this more explicit), they can be described by the static Schwarzschild or stationary Kerr solutions. And it just doesn't make sense to speak about the singularity evolving/moving along in time - it's the 'end point' in time on the conformal diagrams.

Comment: Then, I think Alamar's question may revolve around use of SR concepts (that all objects move thru time with speed c*Lorentz factor) in a GR setting. As such, I wonder if it would help if you (Eletie) considered projecting the Schwarzchild metric (by which I mean the metric that an observer outside the black hole would experience) on the Friedmann-Lemaitre-Robertson-Walker metric? I think this would (at least conceptually) result in what a local observer would "see" of the black hole such that there was a globally defined time. Might doing this better answer your question Alamar?

Comment: But event horizons do move, for example, a black hole may be ejected from a galaxy or two event horizons may merge. This means we can't escape discussing the movement of singularities in 4 dimensions space even if we wanted.

Comment: I don't think Alamar means how the classical black hole changes in and of itself, but how it moves thru time according to an external observer's sense of time. It is certainly the end point of the Schwarzchild solution, but as the universe can end without a big crunch, it need not be the end point of the global manifold. I suspect Alamar is referring to how the black hole appears to exist in space-time external to the local curvature and metric about the black hole. If this is the case, then the question may still be too complicated to be answered here.

Comment: @safesphere I agree with what you say except the very bold claim that astrophysical black holes don't have singularities (as there's no mention of quantum theory, I'll assume you still mean classically). This is in contradiction with the Penrose singularity theorem, which applies to *all* black holes including those formed from collapse. It can also be shown that astrophysical black holes will eventually settle down in finite time and can be described by the Kerr solution, which of course does have a singularity. Now, I'm not saying for definite what exists, but it's clear what GR predicts.

Comment: I suspect we may be getting away from the question. We may be focusing too much on the singularity aspect. What if we were to focus instead on what an external observer could "measure" - the event horizon where absorption of plasma or gas could result in energy emission. (This could allow for the "bubble" around the singularity which alamar mentioned in his original post.) If the event horizon did not move in time, there would be no reason to expect any external observer to be able to cross it because such an event would not exist in the future of any light cone.

Comment: @safesphere I don't know what evidence supports the solid conclusion that trapped surfaces don't form in real systems, and both the stack exchange links you sent clearly do not prove your assertions. Try using papers rather than stack exchange questions as sources, e.g. a revent review 
Maybe you should take a read of the final link you sent, especially when you're on the opposing side to all the textbooks and research in GR

Comment: Review: Senovilla, J. M., & Garfinkle, D. (2015). The 1965 Penrose singularity theorem. Classical and Quantum Gravity, 32(12), 124008. Sending a wiki link to confirmation bias shows you're not interested in actual physics but just trying to 'one up' someone by claiming you know more about GR than the textbooks and papers and researchers in the field. My comments before were describing what classical GR predicts about the structure of spacetime and it's singularities. Now you're just wasting my time, so I'm ending this pointless discussion.